# What is member of the public?

Tags: meaning-in-context, relative-pronouns, singular-they

I read an [article](http://news.sky.com/story/1562663/man-buys-google-com-domain-name-for-12) in which I found the following line:

> It was returned to the open market when ownership expired, and bought by a ***member of the public.***

To my mind, they want to convey that some person has bought it. But then, in ***the following sentence***, 'they contacted the firm' is written, which is probably written for a member of public:

> Thankfully for Microsoft, they had good intentions and immediately ***contacted the firm*** and arranged to hand it over.

My questions is- What is the member of the public here? Is it the common man or someone from the firm?

Comment: As a footnote, that's a very funny article you found!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A *member of the public* indeed refers to a "common person," as your intuition says.

I'll clarify Sentence 2 for you:

> Thankfully for Microsoft, **they** [i.e., **this member of the public**] had good intentions and immediately contacted **the firm** [i.e., **Microsoft**] and arranged to hand it over.

The sentence may be confusing, because the writer is using what is often considered a plural pronoun (*they*) to refer to a single person (the "member of the public"). Presumably, this was done to avoid assigning gender, since it may not be known if this individual was a man or a woman. This usage of *they* is not uncommon, and is referred to as the [singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-specific_and_gender-neutral_pronouns#Singular_they).